# React - dynamic reference for onChange handler

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using Array.map to dynamically create select elements within a table and have set each select element as controlled input.

I am trying to change the value / state dynamically using refs inside my functional component to access state and update the value for the element. To do this I create a ref to each select element when the element is created and store these refs inside a refs array.

I then want to access these refs on a onChange event using the elements key which is set to the .map iteration - but I am struggling to get access to the elements key, see code below:

```
  {state.profitFsHeaders.map((item:any, i:any)=>{
                const newRef:any = createRef()
                rowRefs.push(newRef)

  return (<tr key={i}>
                <td className={classes.tableCell} ref={newRef}>
                {item}
               </td>
               <td className={classes.tableCell}>
                 <select key={i} value={state.mappedPlRows[rowRefs[i].current.innerText]} onChange={(e)=> {handleChange(e,item)}}>
```

The reference to the i variable is undefined -

```
{state.mappedPlRows[rowRefs[i].current.innerText
```

Does anyone know how I preserve this for each element?

Comment: Do you have any additional debugging information, e.g. from dev tools or what `mappedPlRows` is?

Comment: try instead of rowRefs.push -> rowRef.current.push

Comment: rowRefs is just initialised as an empty array and I am pushing the references into it

Answer (score 0):

```
 state.mappedPlRows
```

may not contain values or the value of innertext may be undefined.

Comment: Thakyou, but the issue is with the reference to the i variable within the loop I think not preserving post render